# Why can't I properly install ImageMagick on my mac?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, carrierwave, homebrew, minimagick

I run 'brew install imagemagick' and i get the following error:

```
==> ./configure --disable-osx-universal-binary --without-perl --prefix=/usr/local/
    Cellar      /imagemagick/6.8.7-0 --enable-shared --disable-static --without-pango 
    --with-modules --disable-op
==> make install
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [magick/libMagickCore-6.Q16.la] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

I am trying to manipulate an image in ruby on rails using imagemagick.  In my PicUploader file, I have the following:

```
# include CarrierWave::RMagick
include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
process :resize_to_fit => [50, 41]
```

When I try to upload a picture with RMagick commented out, I receive the following error:

```
Errno::ENOENT in ProfilesController#create
No such file or directory - identify
```

I thought maybe it was referring to RMagick, So I uncomment RMagick and try to do it again, and I get:

```
LoadError in ProfilesController#create
cannot load such file -- RMagick
```

I am using the carrierwave gem and I can get picture uploading to work without using the process method, but i can't get it to work if I want to resize the picture because imagemagick is not installing properly.  How do I fix this?  Thanks.

Comment: What is the output of `which identify` from the command line?

Comment: There is no output. It just returns blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you install x11?  I think you need to if you're on an OS later than Leopard or something.

https://gist.github.com/juandazapata/3182604

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're missing identify, this has worked for me in the past:

```
brew uninstall imagemagick
brew install imagemagick --build-from-source
```

You may need to install png as well.

Assuming you have XCode and the command line tools installed, does installing libtool and then  reinstalling imagemgick fix the issue?

```
brew install libtool --universal
```

Comment: It wouldn't let me uninstall.  When I tried, it says: 'Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick' .  When I run the second command, the same errors appear as before.

Comment: Does installing libtool fix the linking issue at all. Updated response.

Comment: Which version of OS X are you on?

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is very old - I ended up here with this error message: `'/usr/local/opt/imagemagick is not a valid keg'`.

I imagine ImageMagick must have been installed some other way that brew was complaining about, I solved it with the nuclear option:

`rm -r /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick`

Then just ran `brew install imagemagick` again and it worked.